# converting muitiple edittext value to arraylist

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-edittext

I have multiple edit text to enter the name & and the amount and the value which i enter on the edit text should be converted into arraylist and the format should be

```
[{"name": "head light","amount": "30"},{"name": "head light","amount": "30"}]
```

please tell me the way to achieve this. TIA

Comment: First of all tell us what you have did so far ? And second thing you should create first JSONArray and then insert JSONObject (with values name and amount values) into JSONArray. It will provide you above format.

Comment: i have used json to fetch value from database. but i wanted to send the edit text value in the above format

Comment: can you share example for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The format that the line represents is a `JSONArray`.

The `[]` represents an JSONArray and `{}` represents the `JSONObject` .
Example implemetation :-

```
 JSONObject ob1= new JSONObject();
  try {
  ob1.put("name", "1"); 
  ob1.put("amount", "1");
  
} catch (JSONException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  // handle the exception
  e.printStackTrace();
}
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
ja.put(jo);
```

You can add as multiple objects to the array.

Comment: this is showing error on put to surround with try and catch

Comment: ya it is working for the single edit text. what if there are multiple edit text.

Comment: the different values added to the object like the name and amount , you can add multiple edittext text values there. the first element is the key, which should be the values type(or the edittext type like:- name) and second element is the its value(like 1, here).Then each object can be considered as an entry.

Comment: you can also add the different edittext as different jsonobject 's  if that is the requirement.It depends on you requirement or how you plan to retrieve it.